# Dativ plural ohne Artikel

Tags: preposition, article, dative, grammatical-number

I would like to know why the German speakers say *von Leuten* and not *von den Leuten*. Other examples: *an Wochentagen, an Wochenenden*.

When do you use the article *von den* X and when you do not use the article *von* X? Is there any rule for this?

Answer (score 6):

This refers to definite and indefinite articles.

*von den Leuten* is used when you are referring to some *definite*, *specific* people.

> "Von wem hast du die Blumen bekommen?" - "Von den Leuten, die über uns wohnen"

*von Leuten* is used when you are referring to some arbitrary people or "people" in general.

> "Von wem weisst du das?" - "Von (irgendwelchen) Leuten, denen ich auf der Strasse begegnet bin".

Rule of thumb: If you can use "irgendwelche" or "alle" as attribute, you don't use the article.

Same with "Wochentagen"

> An **den** Wochentagen, die mit "M" anfangen, esse ich Fisch

Where we are referring to *specific weekdays*

vs.

> An Wochentagen essen wir keinen Fisch

refers to arbitrary or all weekdays.

Comment: But you can also say *an Wochentagen, die mit "M" anfangen, esse ich Fisch*?

Comment: You can, but it is saying something different.

Comment: In that case the meaning is the same: on all weekdays that start with an M you eat fish. The fact they start with an M makes both variants equally specific.

Comment: I'm not with you on this. Could be one, could be some, could be all of the Weekdays with "M". *an den Wochentagen, die mit "M" anfangen...* is always all of them. That is quite a bit more specific.

Comment: *An Wochentagen, die mit "M" anfangen...* means *On any given weekday that starts with an "M"...* while *An den Wochentangen, die ...* means *On all of the weekdays...*. This describes two equal sets of weekdays, if you want to use mathematical terms :-) You are correct about the article in your other examples and you are correct about *An den Wochentagen, die mit "M" anfangen...* being different from *An Wochentagen essen wir ...*.

Comment: The last two sentences, however, are different in that *An Wochentagen essen wir ...* does not restrict the weekdays, while *An (den) Wochentagen, die mit "M" anfangen...* does (only those starting with "M"). This restriction makes the article obsolete, as I said above. You are comparing apples to peas here by using two different sentences. You should either use the pair *An Wochentagen essen wir* vs. *An den Wochentangen essen wir* or *An Wochentagen, die mit "M" anfangen ...* vs. *An den Wochentagen, die mit "M" anfangen...*.

Answer (score 1):

German has, same as English, three kinds of articles:
(all examples in nominative case)

- definite articles

  - In English:

    > Singular: the
    >   Plural: the
  - In German:

    > Singular (male, female, neuter): der, die, das
    >   Plural: die
- indefinite articles

  - In English:

    > Singular: a, an
    >   (there is no plural indefinite article)
  - In German:

    > Singular (male, female, neuter): ein, eine, ein
    >   (there is no plural indefinite article)
- null articles

  - in all Languages:

    > »null-article« is the name for an article, that consists of zero letters, like the article before »John« in the sentence:
    >   »John is eating.«
    >   (Compare with »*The* man is eating.« and »*A* girl is eating.«

The German word »Leute« is a pluraletantum, which means, it exists only as a plural, there is no singular for »Leute«. And since there is no indefinite plural article in German, you can use »Leute« only with a definite article or with the null-article. A different way to think about this (but with the same result) is to say, that the indefinite plural article *is* the null-article. But this discussion is very academic and in practice makes no difference.

In German we have four cases, and each case has its own definite article (examples in plural here):

- Nominativ:

  > ***Die*** Leute schlafen.
- Genitiv:

  > Die Autos ***der*** Leute stehen auf der Straße.
- Dativ:

  > Der Lärm kommt von ***den*** Leuten.
- Akkusativ:

  > Ich sehe ***die*** Leute.

As in Englisch, you use the definite article, if you mean a certain group of people. If you talk about just any people, you can't use the definite article. But since there is no indefinite plural article, you have to use the null-article.  Genitive case is an exception. Here you have to use the definite article **der** even if you don't mean a certain group of people, but just any people:

- Nominativ:

  > *Leute* schlafen jetzt.
- Genitiv:

  > Die Autos ***der*** Leute stehen auf der Straße.
- Dativ:

  > Der Lärm kommt von *Leuten*.
- Akkusativ:

  > Ich sehe *Leute*.

Use the same pattern for »Wochenenden« and »Wochentage«. If you mean the next and the following weekend, then use the definite article. If you talk about any weekends, use null-article:

> An ***den*** vier Wochenenden im Februar nehme ich an einem Seminar teil.
>   An Wochenenden bin ich meist zu Hause.